# C# How create primary key to existing table column

Tags: c#, datatables, foreign-keys, primary-key, relationship

I would like to ask for your help. The problem is that I am trying to relate two tables so I need  to create primary keys on the tables each "id" columns but I am getting an error on this line

```
ds.Relations.Add(dr);
```

Error:

> This constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding parent values.

(original error in Spanish = *No se puede habilitar esta restricción ya que todos los valores no tienen los valores primarios correspondientes.*)

What am I doing wrong?

```
OdbcDataAdapter sdata = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM componentes WHERE nombre_componente ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%'", conn);
OdbcDataAdapter sdata2 = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM proveedores WHERE nombre_empresa ILIKE '%" + buscar + "%'", conn);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

DataTable dtbl = new DataTable("dtbl");
DataTable dtbl2 = new DataTable("dtbl2");

sdata.Fill(dtbl);
sdata2.Fill(dtbl2);

ds.Tables.Add(dtbl);
ds.Tables.Add(dtbl2);

dtbl.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtbl.Columns["id"] };
dtbl2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtbl2.Columns["id"] };

DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("provcomp",
                ds.Tables["dtbl"].Columns["id_prov_comp"],
                ds.Tables["dtbl2"].Columns["id"]);

ds.Relations.Add(dr);
ds.AcceptChanges();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not seen people use the primary and foreign key value in c# they just use linq to achieve what they require. what is your goal why do you need this precisely

Comment: The problem is not in the Primary Key but in the DataRelation. To create a DataRelation all values in the child table must be in the parent table. The  most common reason it's having 0 (instead of null) in the child table (id_prov_comp in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary keys are ok - you already successfully created them with the following lines:

```
dtbl.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtbl.Columns["id"] };
dtbl2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtbl2.Columns["id"] };
```

The problem is (as indicated by the exception) in the `DataRelation`. `DataRelation` is the equivalent of the database FK (foreign key). The signature of the used constructor looks like this:

```
public DataRelation(
    string relationName,
    DataColumn parentColumn,
    DataColumn childColumn
)
```

I think what you did wrong is specifying the wrong columns - `parentColumn` should point to the table being referenced while `childColumn` - the table referencing it.

Simple change it to:

```
DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("provcomp",
    ds.Tables["dtbl2"].Columns["id"],
    ds.Tables["dtbl"].Columns["id_prov_comp"]);
```

and if they are really related correctly, the problem should be solved.

**Edit:** In case the parent table does not contain all the keys from the child table, you might consider using this constructor [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2ctayxw(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass `createConstraints = false`, which will prevent the exception, but note that some child records will not to find their parent record.

```
DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("provcomp",
    ds.Tables["dtbl2"].Columns["id"],
    ds.Tables["dtbl"].Columns["id_prov_comp"],
    false);
```

Comment: It worked partially... This code is triggered by a "search input" on a texbox, if i type it should search in both tables and fill a form witch contains controls from the two tables together. Typing something that i know its in te partent table, does not give me the error, but typing something that is on the childtable gets same error again.

Comment: Well, this is totally different issue. The relation requires parent table to contain all the FKs from the child table. May be you don't need relation at all. In any case, it's beyond the scope of your current question, which I think the answer is covering.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your data. You're adding a primary key to each table and then attempting to link them with a foreign key.

However, from the error message you are receiving, it sounds like you are attempting to link dtbl to an id from dtbl2 which does not exist.

I would try to do a SQL query to find out where your problem records lie and then choose to either add a "parent", change the parent or delete the record.

```
SELECT * FROM componentes WHERE id_prov_comp NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM proveedores )
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent column (that is primary key) must come before the child column (that is foreign key). Try this:

```
DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("provcomp",
            ds.Tables["dtbl2"].Columns["id"],
            ds.Tables["dtbl"].Columns["id_prov_comp"]);
```